##[error]The term 'New-AzActionGroupReceiver' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
I was running a powershell script and it was throwing the error
##[error]The term 'New-AzActionGroupReceiver' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
As it belongs to the module, Az.Monitor, I tried installing it before the command
"New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name $name -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress $item"
is executed. I installed the module using
Install-Module -Name Az.Monitor -Force
the error still remained the same
I was running the script over an azure devops pipeline, despite my attempt to install the module and deploy, it failed

Looks like the issue is with the version,thanks for the inputs @Vinay B the cmdlets which we have been using might be deprecated, we can use the below commands, instead of the commands which we have used before, i.e., use
New-AzActionGroupEmailReceiverObject -Name $name -EmailAddress $item
instead of
New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name $name -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress $item
and use
New-AzActionGroup -Name $ActionGroupName -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -ShortName $ActionGroupShortName -Location $DefaultLocation -EmailReceiver $actionGroupEmailReceiver
instead of
Set-AzActionGroup -Name $ActionGroupName -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -ShortName $ActionGroupShortName -Location $DefaultLocation -EmailReceiver $actionGroupEmailReceiver
